# How to put sub shell and related commands in background?

Tags: shell-script, background-process, subshell

Run a sequence commands in a sub shell like this:

```
(git pull;git rebase develop)&>/dev/null
```

I think this will put the sub shell and all children processes created by it in background, and return control to user.

But actually, the terminal hang up for a while, seems it is wait for the commands to finish in sub shell.

So can anyone explain why this happened, and what is the right way to do this kind of job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running the `bash` shell, then `&>/dev/null` will redirect the standard output and error streams to `/dev/null` (it's the same as `>/dev/null 2>&1`), but it won't run the `( ... )` subshell as an asynchronous process. For that, you'll need to add an extra `&` at the end:

```
(git pull; git rebase develop) &>/dev/null &
```

`ksh93` doesn't have this feature, and it's not in POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `sleep` in your case and `&` at the end of command to put them in background,

```
(git pull; sleep 3; git rebase develop) &>/dev/null &
```

---

Alternatively you can use,

```
for cmd in $commands
do
    "$cmd" &
done
wait
```

The `&` at the end of the command runs it in the background, and the `wait` waits until the background task is completed.